# Schema selection for postgresql tables with sqlalchemy

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, schema

I am trying to create a table named "networks" via the following code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': ''}

    def __init__(self, schema, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        Base.__table_args__['schema'] = schema

class DBNetwork(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'networks'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(sa.String(60))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:pass@localhost/test', 
                              pool_size=20, max_overflow=0)
    Base('test')

    with engine.connect() as connection:
        connection.execute(sa.schema.CreateSchema(
            Base.__table_args__['schema'], if_not_exists=True))
        connection.commit()
    Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
```

I am defining the `Base` with `__table_args__ = {'schema': ''}`, so that it will create tables in public schema when not called. And when called I may be able to create the tables in the desired schema.

However, it seems like `Base.metadata` is already created with `DBNetwork.__table_args__ = {'schema': ''}` so it does not recognize my schema selection via `Base('test')`.

What can I implement in my code so that I can select schema and create my tables in this schema? I do not want to hard code for each child class of Base `__table_args__ = {'schema': 'test'}`.

BTW, after `Base('test')`, if you print the `__table_args__` of `DBNetwork`:

```
print(DBNetwork.__table_args__)
{'schema': 'test'}
```